# what will be the output if write for loop in c like this?

Tags: c

I know that the for loop syntax is like :

```
for(initialise; condition ; increament/decreament)
```

but what will be the output for the following:

```
for( ; ; )
{
printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: `hello worldhello worldhello world...` forever and ever

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: It's equivalent to `while(true) {...}`

Comment: It's an infinite loop.

Comment: why it is assuming the second condition true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with standards for C in general.

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement
>
> The statement
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
>   expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>   The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any identiﬁers it declares is the remainder of the
>   declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>   it is reached in the order of execution before the ﬁrst evaluation of
>   the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the ﬁrst evaluation of the
>   controlling expression.
>
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted expression-2
>   is replaced by a nonzero constant.**

**References**

1. *WG14/N1256 Committee DraftISO/IEC 9899:TC3*, Accessed 2014-04-29, [`<http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf>`](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
2. *Why can the condition of a for-loop be left empty?*, Accessed 2014-04-29, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366290/why-can-the-condition-of-a-for-loop-be-left-empty>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366290/why-can-the-condition-of-a-for-loop-be-left-empty)

Answer (score 0):

No conditions are specified in the `for` loop, therefore the loop will run forever.

https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Infinite_loop.html

Answer (score 0):

That will loop forever, printing Hello World every time through the loop. Another way to achieve this same result is by doing:

```
while(1){
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Also use indentation. it helps with readability (not a problem in your example, but with bigger problems it would be an issue.