# Why does C# also not allow empty conditions in while loops?

Tags: c#, c, language-design, language-specifications

**Edit: I changed most of my question, because it was too long and altough my question is a request of facts, it was considered opinion based.** Having said that, please read the comments where I try to explain why closing this question was wrong IMHO.

**<sub>Also: I'd like to appologize for my initial question, I am not a native English speaker and I didn't know the word [blindly] had such a negative tone. I actually used the word in other questions.</sub>**

---

**Background**:

Consider the following piece of C# code:

```
for(; /*empty condition*/ ;)
{
    //Infinite loop   
}
```

This amongst other methods is considered good practice to make an infinite loop. But when we would try a similar approach with a `while loop` it would never compile:

```
while(/*empty condition*/)
{
    //Compiler error
}
```

At first I thought that this was some sort of bug in my compiler, but then I read the `C# language specification`. I found this was be design. Why? Because C# is based on C, and C behaves this way.

So now the question is, why does C behave like this? [Somebody else asked this question on StackOverflow already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146830/no-loop-condition-in-for-and-while-loop). The answer was pretty unsatisfying and came down to this:

> It behaves like this because it is described like this in the C language specification.

This answer reminded me of many discussions I had with my parents when I was a kid: *"Why do I have to clean my room?" - "Because we say so."*. Further answers speculate (i.e. no sources or arguments were added) that `while()` is *"hacky"* and that *"using `for(;;)` made more sense"*.

---

**My research**

Edit: deleted because it was considered to long. It basically was an effort to figure out why C had this construction.

---

**My question:**

After all my research I concluded that the `while loop`'s inability to accept empty expressions is illogical if `the for loop` can.

But if that is true, then why did the C# language design team copy this bevahiour?

You: *"C# is based on C and why would you reinvent the wheel?"*

True, but why make the same illogical decissions? If your grandfather would jump of a bridge, then would you do it too, just because you are based on him? And isn't the creation of a new language - based on an old one - the ideal situation to avoid/fix the illogical pitfalls of the old language?

So to repeat my question:

- Why did the C# design team copy this behaviour?

Comment: I've changed the title for you.  Feel free to change it to something more appropriate if you can think of anything.  The original was... inviting downvotes.  Personally I think it's an interesting question, though arguably only tangentially topical for Stack Overflow.  If you're lucky, however, there are members of the C# design team here who may stumble across this and provide a first-hand answer...

Comment: Why the `C` tag???? I don't know C# but can't you do `while(1)`?

Comment: @Devolus: `while(true)` would be idiomatic C# for an infinite while loop.

Comment: @David, so if C# has such a construct, why the lengthy posting???

Comment: Why should the C# team have deviated from well known usage? C, Java, C++, behave in similar manner. The C# team wanted to design a language that would be familiar to other developers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, believe me when I say I didn't mean to offend anyone. Off-topic not so much. Very long, yes, but I searched around and it doesn't seem to be discouraged to make long questions.

Comment: @Devolus: Perhaps there's more to it at the language/compiler level than I'm aware.  I do think it's a bit silly when the construct exists.  And now that I look at it, putting an *actual condition* in the loop (such as `true`) makes the code more explicitly readable.  I'd be interested to hear from an expert in language/compiler design about the differences "under the hood" in something like this, though.

Comment: @Devolus, the c tag is because c is explicitly discussed in the question.

Comment: @Jordy Just wondering, what does it matter to you if you discover the "real reason"? At the end of the day, you'll just have to accept it as a quirk of C and C# and move on.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is opinion-based? I spent literal hours researching and writing this question. A similar question has been asked regarding C, but when the # is added, it suddenly becomes opinion-based?

Comment: @Jjj this is opinion based because there is no canonical answer. I don't think this can be answered without being a primarily opinionated answer. The only people that could answer it is probably the C# language designers. Secondly, stackoverflow's rules have evolved over the years. A question that is not closed does not mean it is an example of a good question.

Comment: @vcsjones, I gave it some thought and I am afraid I have to disagree. There are people on StackExchange who actually now this. (e.g. Eric Lippert worked for Microsoft and I can imagine him knowing this.) The fact that people answer with: "IMHO", or "to speculate", is their fault, not mine. I agree if my question was: "Can anyone guess why this is?" or "Which Hindu God do you think is responsible for this?" (I kid of course), but I am simply asking for facts, that perhaps some stackoverflow members may now, or perhaps they don't but the question itself isn't opinion-based.

Comment: @Jjj: I used to be wonder a lot at the reason for things the way you seem to. While there are times that an understanding the historical reasons for things can be useful, insightful, or both, a lot of the time bad decisions are made for the simple reason "it seemed like a reasonable choice, and it wasn't worth spending too much time on", and good decisions are made for the simple reason "I arbitrarily chose something I figured would work okay, and it happened to work better than expected." An imperfect project which ships is better than a one that would potentially be perfect but never ships.

Comment: @Jjj: Another thing to consider is that even people who made momentous decisions sometimes regard them as mistakes whether or not they were. Even though Tony Hoare regards null pointers as a mistake, for example, they're better than any practical alternative. Every Turing-complete language must make it possible to specify a program that would read a storage location for which no *useful* value has been written. A language could mandate that all items of an array be written before any can be read, but in some cases that would mean storing values that couldn't possibly be useful.

Comment: @Jjj: The main time I would regard 'why' questions as useful would be in cases where one is pondering a future design and wants to know if there might have been any ideas which were initially attractive but were later found unwise; such information could help a future designer avoid such mistakes. For example, someone designing a language might want to know what whether C#'s use of the same token for member access of value types and reference types (in contrast to C's uses `.` and `->`) was an effort to avoid some problem, or was simply following Java's use of `.` for indirect member access.

Answer (score 3):

> After all my research I can only conclude that the while loop's inability to accept empty expressions is illogical.

A very far fetched conclusion. IMHO it is the `for(;;)` loop that is illogical (and not only in this respect).

It is clear that `while() { ... }` would have been possible but what exactly is the merit?
As a matter of style I would prefer `for(;true;)` over `for(;;)`, it has less chance of being misread.

Being able to write a 'for-ever' loop is a minor issue, avoiding typos is much more important.
Readability is the only thing that counts, you're not making much of a case for `while()`.

And what should happen in this statement?

```
 if() Foo();
```

Comment: Typos are important, so wile(){...} should be: while(){....}

Comment: I guess you're right... I just assumed that since the for has more functionality the while loop would have a problem. I was kind of proud of what I was managed to research, but the word blindly in my title and being to enthusiastic in my post gave my question a whole lot of uninvited attention. If I knew that I would have never asked it.

Answer (score 1):

C11 specification states:

> 1. The statement
>
>    `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )` statement
>
>    behaves as follows: The expression *expression-2* is the
>      controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the
>      loop body. The expression *expression-3* is evaluated as a void
>      expression after each execution of the loop body. If *clause-1* is a
>      declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder
>      of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two
>      expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first
>      evaluation of the controlling expression. If *clause-1* is an
>      expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
>      evaluation of the controlling expression. 158)
> 2. **Both *clause-1* and *expression-3* can be omitted. An omitted *expression-2* is replaced by a
>      nonzero constant.**

which is not the case with the *while-loop*. However this is C11. ANSI C doesn't make this clear really. Though, I assume C# is based on how C most commonly work(s|ed), not how it's specified to work.

To speculate, I could think that the *for-loop* in early C wasn't well defined, so programmers found out that you can write an infinite loop like `for (;;)`. To be compatible with old programs, the standards never forbid this. So there is really no reason to write like this. It's just history I guess.

Comment: I know, I read it myself. The question is about why the for-loop would accept such a construct and the while-loop wouldn't.