# Whats the meaning of "for(;;)"

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax

Moin,
I just found a for-loop in some source code.

```
for (;;) {
    // some work
    if (condition) {
       break;
    }
}
```

How is this  `for (;;)`  working ?

Comment: for till eternity unless god living inside it breaks it

Comment: What did your beginner level C book say when you checked there?

Comment: Relevant: [No loop condition in for and while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146830/no-loop-condition-in-for-and-while-loop)

Comment: Any or all of the three components of a `for` statement may be left blank.  If all are blank, then there is no initialization, no exit test, and no increment section.  The behavior follows immediately from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `for(;;)` is an infinite loop.

As per `C11`, chapter §6.8.5.3, *The `for` statement*,

> The statement
>   `for` ( *clause-1* `;` *expression-2* `;` *expression-3* ) *statement*
>   behaves as follows: The expression *expression-2* is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body.[...]

and (*emphasis mine*)

> Both *clause-1* and *expression-3* can be omitted. **An omitted *expression-2* is replaced by a
>   nonzero constant.**

Also, for the usage of the *controlling expression*

> An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be executed repeatedly
>   until the *controlling expression* compares equal to 0. [...]

So, in case, all three are removed, the controlling expression is considered as non-zero, which is TRUE forever, thus essentially making it an infinite loop.

Comment: This is a nice formal answer, although in this spirit I think you should mention that a no-op infinite loop is UB.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, it's not UB. Please see  §6.8.5/6 and footnote 157.

Answer (score 3):

It's an infinite loop, like

```
while (1)
```

That was mostly used befroe because some compiler complain when they detected an infinite loop with while(1).

The three part of for is optionnal, so if the initialisation part is missing, then there is no initialization, if the test part is missing, it's assume that's true, etc.

Comment: thanks, i will accept your answer in a short time. I knew that there is the ;; null expression/statement in c but i thought  the test part will evaluate to false if there is none...

Answer (score 3):

```
for (;;) {
    // some work
    if (condition) {
       break;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
do
{
  //some work
}while(!condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this as "forever". 
It repeats the block until the condition is met, and the `break` statement is executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop.
It means the loop will keep execution until you use break or exit function.

Comment: Or the `return` statement.

Comment: ..or goto... . (sorry:)